# Returning undefined on an object created by a class

Tags: javascript, class, this

Why is this object created based on a class returning undefined? shouldn't it return the 'red'?

```
this.name='red' // global.name
class foo {
    constructor(name){
        this.name= name
        return function (){
            console.log(this.name); // new object is gonna return only this
        }
    }
}
let oof = new foo ('green');
console.log(oof) //name is not defined. Expected to return 'red' (global)
oof(); //cannot read the property
function color () {
    console.log(this.name);
}
color(); //red
```

thanks!

*Edit1*: I misswrote the `oof`. Corrected now.

*Edit2*: So guys, I know that a constructor usually don't take a return (it wouldn't make sense) and that the `this` keyword refers to the object that's going to be created. The thing here is that I was trying to test the limits of the `this`. In a normal function, `this.name`would return 'red' as it's called in the global scope. Why it's not working in this case? because it's a function created by a class?

*Edit3*: To make it clear, I added another function `color`, which is supposed to be the same as `oof` (both are functions and called on the window) but refering the globalThis (red). The only difference is the way the are constructed.

Comment: what is `off()`? (btw the constructor makes no sense to return something)

Comment: What is happening ?  Want to call a constor or what !

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here:
Fist, you can't return that function from the constructor, you may want to set it as a property:

```
this.name='red' // global.name
class foo {
    constructor(name){
        this.name= name
        this.sayName = function (){
            console.log(this.name); // 
        }
    }
}
let oof = new foo ('green');
oof.sayName()
```

Note: on classes we usually add function as methods, not directly as a property like i just did.

The second issue is scope, you are binding the name property to the instanced object so you won't directly change global.name, but 'this.name' => oof.name instead.

**Remember**: when dealing with classes, 'this' will always refer to the instance object.

Answer (score 1):

The **this** reference is not what you are expecting in your code. The rule of thumb is: "within the context of a function, this takes the value of the object effectively invoking that function".

When you do `oof()` there is no object invoking it, in despite you would have expected the global scope to have been passed to **oof** that's not the case.

If you want your code to work as you have your function defined you could try `({name:'surprise', oof}).oof()`. Here you see there's an object with an attribute **name** invoking your function and that's the object **this** refers to within **oof**.

For more info on how **this** works you could take a look do MDN docs on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: 'When you do oof() there is no object invoking it, in despite you would have expected the global scope to have been passed to oof that's not the case.' This is what i'm originally asking, why the global scope ain't working? in a normal function, the this would refer to the global scope. And at the end of the day it's a function created by a class constructor, right?

Comment: Classes don't follow the exact same rules than functions declared in the global scope. When you create a new instance of a class it internally creates an object onto which to bind the invocation of the constructor. You can also read the docs for [Binding this with prototype and static methods
](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#binding_this_with_prototype_and_static_methods)

Answer (score 0):

1.- typo: `off()` seems to be `oof()`
2.- with the `return function() {}` you are going one scope ahead, so the this does not refer to the class anymore but to the returned function.

This is what you might be after:

```
this.name='red' // global.name
class foo {
  constructor(name){
      this.name= name
      return this.logger();
  }
  logger() {
    console.log(this.name); // 
  }
}
let oof = new foo ('green');
oof() //name is not defined. Expected to return 'red' (global)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after 3 days of headache and thanks to the replies I think I got the solution:

- When declared a Class in ES6, `use strict` is always enabled. More at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_classes
- In strict mode, the `this` won't refer anymore to the global object (making it more secure to write your code) More at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#securing_javascript
- So, as [Eduardo Hernández](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958747/16482602) said, we should create an object to call a function created by a class and using the `this` correctly.
  Example:

```
    this.name='red' // global.name
    function color(){
        'use strict'
        console.log(this.name);
    }
    class Color  {
        constructor(){
            return function (){
                console.log(this.name)
            }
        }
    }
    let foo= new Color();
    let newObj= {name: 'blue',foo,color}
    newObj.color(); //blue
    newObj.foo();  // blue
```